# How to pass a JSON object from Svelte to Quarkus

Tags: rest, axios, svelte, quarkus

I'm playing with **Svelte** on the frontend and **Quarkus** on the backend.

I'm finding myself unable to get an object passed from the front to the backend's **search** method.

Help is appreciated.

```
   let endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/api/users/search";
   
   async function apiCall() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(endpoint, {
           headers: {},
           params: {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'}
        });

        //...
      } catch (e) {
      }
   }


@Path("/api/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {
    
    //...
    
    @POST
    @Path("/search")
    public Response search(User user) {
        String name = user.getName();
        //This throws a NullPointerException because user is null
        
        //...   
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Simply:

```
let data = {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'};
const res = await axios.post(endpoint, data)
```